# Sending Raw ZPL command to print label - Not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF application that is supposed to print labels from a Zebra printer. The label's ZPL code is already generated and when I print the ZPL code from a text editor such as Notepad or Notepad++, the label prints perfectly fine. When I print the same string from my WPF application, I got command printed on the label as shown in the image.

**XAML file code**

```
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ZebraTesting"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Button Content="TEST-1" Name="test1" Click="test1_Click"></Button>

            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="TEST-2" Name="test2" Click="test2_Click"></Button>


        </Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CS File code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ZebraTesting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void test1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog prnt = new PrintDialog();
            prnt.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
            prnt.UserPageRangeEnabled = false;

            Nullable<bool> result = prnt.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {

                PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
                pdoc.PrintPage += ProvideContent;
                pdoc.Print();
            }

        }

        public void ProvideContent(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

            string zpl = "^XA" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "^A0N,23,31^FDAsset ID:^FS" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "^XZ" + Environment.NewLine;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(zpl, new Font("Arial", 10), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 0, 0, new StringFormat());

        }


        private void test2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog prnt = new PrintDialog();
            prnt.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
            prnt.UserPageRangeEnabled = false;

            Nullable<bool> result = prnt.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {

                string zpl = "^XA" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "^A0N,23,31^FDAsset ID:^FS" + Environment.NewLine +
                    "^XZ" + Environment.NewLine;

                var doc = new FlowDocument();
                doc.ColumnWidth = prnt.PrintableAreaWidth;

                Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                p.Inlines.Add(zpl);
                doc.Blocks.Add(p);
                prnt.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator, "Label A0000001");

                //doc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(zpl)));
                //prnt.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator, "Label A0000001");
                //prnt.PrintDocument((Section)XamlReader.Parse(zpl));                 

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**I am getting command print as it is instead of printing just text**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugSs6.jpg)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you sending Raw?  When you print from Notepad a driver is being used and it is working.  You should be using the same print method in your WPF app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print raw data to a thermal-printer using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638988/print-raw-data-to-a-thermal-printer-using-net)

Comment: @jdweng I want to print barcode label sticker using this code for POS system so I am using it but if you have any another approach can you please share with me ?

Comment: The same commands that you use with Notepad will not work with RAW because Notepad is going through a driver.  Can you add the driver to the POS?

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for reply but I am sorry to say that I am not able to add the driver to the pos do you have any code which will able to print the label through coding

Comment: I found manual.  You are using a driver (not raw) which is causing issue.  The driver is printing the ascii characters instead of sending the escape sequences.  If you really were connecting raw the code would work.  See following manual starting at page 46 : https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf.  The print class in c# uses a driver.